# Connecting to a remote monitor using the monitor's native resolution

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors

HP Mini 210 Netbook screen 1024x600
    Intel graphics 3100
    External Monitor 1360x768
    Linux Fedora

Everytime I connect my netbook to my monitor I thought that the screen resolution on the monitor would use its native setting. However, when I connect it uses a screen resolution size 1024x768.

My question is, is there anyway I can use the monitor native resolution which should be 1360x768?

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2048 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected 1024x600+0+168 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 222mm x 125mm
   1024x600       60.0*+
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1024x768+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: That video chipset may not support that resolution with the driver in use.  (I have no idea because I don't use Linux, but I am confident the chipset IN THEORY can drive that resolution.)

Comment: And xrandr with it *connected*?

Comment: @lgnacio, I have updated my question. Thanks.